Missing vertical space at section end due to lstinputlisting
I have discovered that if a section contains an \lstinputlisting, the following section title will be typeset without the usual vertical skip (even if the listing is not the last vbox)... but only if the top rule of the frame of the listing is not present! Why? What is the connection here, where is the bug, and what is the recommended practice for typesetting with \lstinputlisting?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\showoutput
\lstinputlisting
[frame=t,backgroundcolor={\color[gray]{0.9}}]
{hi.txt}
Listing with top rule in frame.

\subsection{Subsection}
\lstinputlisting
[frame=brl,backgroundcolor={\color[gray]{0.9}}]
{hi.txt}
Listing without top rule in frame.

\subsection{Subsection}
Normal paragraph.

\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}



You can reproduce without the colour, which removes one source of complications.

You get the same problem with this example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lstinputlisting{hi.txt}%

some text after the listing

\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}


The problem is that the listing is directly after the \subsection command without a normal paragraph in-between. Sectioning commands set \@nobreaktrue. If a normal paragraph follows, this paragraph then resets the switch to \@nobreakfalse in \everypar (and that is what happens if you use a top line: it is a normal paragraph and can issue the \everypar before listings changes it). This systems allows a directly following sectioning command to detect that no text was between the two sectioning commands and to adjust the spacing.
But \lstinputlisting overwrites the \everypar but forgets to reset the \@nobreak switch itself and so confuses the following sectioning commands that now suppresses the space.
That is a bug in listings and should be reported to the maintainer. A temporary patch could be this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\lst@inputlisting{\ignorespaces}{\@nobreakfalse\ignorespaces}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lstinputlisting{hi.txt}%

some text after the listing

\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}



Thank you! How come a normal paragraph following the listing does not trigger \everypar itself, thus resetting to \@nobreakfalse? Are you saying that \everypar is permanently overwritten by lstinputisting?

yes, try \showthe\everypar before and after the lstinputlisting. That is also the reason why the other answer works: if there is group \everypar is restored and the next paragraph can set the switch (but naturally only if there is a actually some text after the listing).

Problem solved by putting the \lstinputlisting between braces (or \bgroup \endgroup)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
  hi
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \showoutput
  \lstinputlisting
  [frame=t,backgroundcolor={\color[gray]{0.9}}]
  {\jobname.txt}
  Listing with top rule in frame.
  
  \subsection{Subsection}
  { % or \bgroup
  \lstinputlisting
  [frame=brl,backgroundcolor={\color[gray]{0.9}}]
  {\jobname.txt}
  } % or \egroup
  Listing without top rule in frame.
  
  \subsection{Subsection}
  Normal paragraph.
  
  \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}



But I can't answer the why…
